# uiRouter ui-view is not populated by nested state templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to have two different templates loaded into a `ui-view`, depending on the state. The problem is that when I go to either of the states (`coupon.form` and `coupons.login`) neither of them populate `coupon`'s `ui-view`. What am I doing wrong?

#### uiRouter Code

```
angular.module('couponGeneratorApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('coupons', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/generate-coupons',
        template: '</ui-view>'
      })
      .state('coupons.form', {
        url: '',
        template: '<h1> HELLO FORM </h1>'
      })
      .state('coupons.login', {
        url: '',
        template: '<h1> HELLO LOGIN</h1>'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template in the 'coupons' state should be `'<ui-view />'`, not `'</ui-view>'`